# C# Console - If no arguments were passed take user input

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have a C#-Console-Program that gets called by another program.

The other Program is supposed to pass an argument to my program.

Now, in case there is no argument passed to the program, I want to make it so that the user inputs an argument into the `args` string array of the `Main` function.

I know that you can check for the length of the `args` string to see whether it has something in it or not like this:

```
 if(args.Length == 0){}
```

But I dont seem to get it so that the user can input a new value into the console into the `args` array.

I already tried it like this:

```
if(args.Length == 0)
        {
            args[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But it only throws an error because there is the Index is out of range.

Is there a way to add an index to the `args`-array or any other way to handle this case? Or do I need to rewrite my code so that it doesnt take the `args`-Array directly but instead checks if the array has an argument in it and if not create a new array?

Comment: You need to rewrite your code as you describe.

Comment: because your length actually is 1 if the args[0] has been initialized.

Comment: which means you must create instance of new object in args[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be:

```
String username, password;

if (args.Length >= 1) username = args[0];
else username = Console.ReadLine();

if (args.Length >= 2) password = args[1];
else password = Console.ReadLine();
```

That way you get meaningful variables instead of a dumb array;

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
         // args[0] does not exist because it is an empty array.
         // assign it with an new array of string instead.
         args = new string[] { Console.ReadLine(), };
    }
```

Comment: Modifying a parameter passed by value is a terrible idea. There are so many ways that can burn you that I make a general rule not to do it. In one particularly memorable case, due to the way LINQ's deferred execution works, modifying the input parameter resulted in an infinite loop. This is one of those practices that seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do ... until you're debugging and need to see the original value, or some weird bug crops up and the cause is completely non-obvious.